# click listeners for dynaically added imageview

Tags: android

I have an activity in my app which displays rss feeds and next to each rss feed arrow image is attached.

I am new to android any help will be appreciated.

i shall explain what i am doing to display rss news ...

i have a seperate dummy xml layout for a single rss.. i have set id for arrow image (which will navigate to the next activity) in it as iv_arrow_img
i am iterating over the news feeds i get and for each news feed i am adding the dummy view again and again...my question is how will i distinguish between different image arrow's ids .. because for now all are having the same id... how will i set onclick listeners to them ???

.....
@devA
taking ur suggestions i have wrote the code
         Iterator itr = data.iterator();
            int i =0;
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
            NewsPostDTO newspostdto = itr.next();

```
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rl_news_item, null);
        lnContentView.addView(view, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);


        ivArrowfwd = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrowfwd);

        tvNewsHeading.setText(newspostdto.getFeaturedDesc());
        tvNewsContent.setText(newspostdto.getDate() + " - " + newspostdto.getTitle());
        ivArrowfwd.setId(id);
        ivArrowfwd.setTag(newspostdto);
        ivArrowfwd.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                               System.out.println("sdfsdf" +(ImageView) view.findViewById(id).getTag());

                return false;
            }
        });
        id++;
    }
```

but i am not gettng different tags for each news thought they are unique .. can u tell me where i am doing wrong... ?

Comment: why r u adding same image again n again..?

Comment: i have to place an arrow image against each news feed i am displaying... ..

Comment: for every news u need to navigate to diff activity..?

Comment: nopes same activity but content will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this, Since its not clear what layouts you are using and how you are attaching the view to the layouts,

One way would be this, When you are populating view dynamically, use a method called    setTag("uniqueid") on the view,

unique id may be url or something else which is unique to the view and you store them in array, Once views are populated, iterate the array , use findViewWithTag("uniqueid")    and set the listener.

Comment: ok i added the listners but how will i get those views in onClick() method...  like for example when i a getting it using R.id.arrowimgView .. it just does nothing ??? i have to change the ids of the imageviews also ???

Comment: onClick(View v) , use v.getTag() and u will get unique id and you can differentiate the views depending on that.

Answer (score 0):

then there is no issue at all..

```
`image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

@Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
//start your activity..
})
```

` to image.. with the current reference and inside it startActivity.. no need to have diff id's..

Comment: @devA i have updated he post plz tell me where i am doing wrong

Comment: remove that println() method and start the activity using startActivity(context,yourActivityname.class);

Comment: actually i have to pass the new spost Id to my actiivity which will be unique for each news item .. i have used prinln for debugging.. when i click on the view getTag() give me the last id i have set to the imageview in tag .. not the associated tag ...

Comment: then create static variable and put it as id of imageView and increment it each time u create imageView..

Comment: i have updated the code above but i am getting nullpointer exception because i am using the id with which no view exists ... can u elaborate it more how will i use that id ??